# How to set and get multiple values(array values) to Single attribute in Active Directory using C++ win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ldap, adsi

i am using C++ Win32 API.

i have done to connect AD using ldap functions & create a attribute.

i done to set & get single values to attributes from AD.

Now,i want to set multiple values in myown attribute.the attribute name is 
"UsrAttrib".

how to set array of value into this attribute?

And i already tried to get "objectClass" attribute value,using below code.

```
usrValue = ldap_get_values(
                          pLdapConnection,  // Session Handle
                          pEntry,           // Current entry
                          "ObjectClass");
```

the attribute actual value is `top;person;organizationalPerson;user`

But `usrValue` only gives `top` only.

and i check using `ldap_count_values` it gives `4`.

How to i get all values from that attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all of the values of a particular attribute use `ldap_count_values` and `ldap_get_values` on the result of a search for the attribute. See the [Searching a Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367016.aspx) example.

To set multiple values for a particular attribute you can list them all in the `mod_values` member of the `ldapmod` structure, or you can create multiple `LDAP_MOD_ADD` structures.

Comment: @SanjuMonu What do you mean by `usrValue` only gives "top"? It's an array, so `usrValue[0]` should be "top", `usrValue[1]` should be "person" etc.